# If $A^a + B^b = C$, can we have $A^x + B^y = C$ as well? Where '$x$' not equal to '$a$' and '$y$' not equal to '$b$', $C$ not equal to $1.$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $A^a + B^b = C$, can we have $A^x + B^y = C$ as well?

Where '$x$' not equal to '$a$' and '$y$' not equal to '$b$', $C$ not equal to $1.$

I know it is true when $C=1.$

$ 3^1 - 2^1 = 1\;;$

$ 2^2 - 3^1 = 4-3 = 1\;;$

$3^2 - 2^3 = 9 - 8 = 1\;.$

Is there any theorem to prove or disprove this?

Comment: $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is the only solution to $6^x + (-3)^y = 3$.

Comment: You haven't specified whether x,y are integer or even negative; or even a,b,A,B,C.  Over the reals conditional statements might be made; over the Complex numbers it can always be made if multivalued functions are allowed.

Comment: $2^4+3^5 = 259 = 2^8+3^1$ Don't know, whether more examples exist, but if there are some at all, they should have place on a very short list...

Comment: Keyword "Pillai"'s problems, "perfect powers"; authors two at the top of my head M.A.Bennet , Michel Waldschmidt

Comment: @GottfriedHelms thank you for your help. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might look at articles like this one, which shows, that there seems something to be open still. Here a screenshot to see how the status has been at 2004. The screenshot might give you as well many keywords with which you can search for more general and modern (and, perhaps, older and still interesting) results:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @GottfriedHelms.- Lovely reference.